# Mongodb : Replace or add multilanguage text

Tags: mongodb, spring-data

I have collection that supports multilanguage text, like that

```
{
    "_id": "xxx",
    "title": [
        {
            "lang": "en",
            "text": "fr"
        }
    ]
}
```

My problem appears when I want to modify my document by working on the multilanguage object.

What I'm looking for is when modifying the field `title`, the text will be added if the language does not exist, or replaced if the language already exists.

What i tried is delete the old object, and add a new object with the new text, but the problem is that mongo does not support `pull` and `push` on the same field in a single update operation.

Is there any way to do that without using bulk update? like doing that in a single update operation

Comment: Which version of MongoDB?

Comment: Hi @Joe, i m using the 4.2 version